# Jquery get not working in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Im newbie on JS and React. While im watching online course and following it i get some problem with jquery. cant explain it well seems like but alert in jquery does not work no idea why.

```
 $.get(url, function(result) {
    alert("working");
});
```

Source code is here

> [Lesson link](https://laracasts.com/series/do-you-react/episodes/7)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="app"></div>
      <script type="text/babel">
      var Gist = React.createClass({

        render: function() {

            return 
            (
                <div>
                    {this.props.username}'s last Gist is <a href={this.props.url}>here</a>.
                </div>
            );
        }

      });

      var GistAddForm= React.createClass({

        getInitialState: function() {
             return {
                username: ''
             };
        },

        onChange: function(e) {
            this.setState({ username: e.target.value });
        },

        addGist: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault;
            this.props.onAdd(this.state.username);
            this.setState({ username: '' });
        },

        render: function() {

            return(
                <div>
                    <form onSubmit={this.addGist}>
                        <input value={this.state.username} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Type a Github username... " />
                        <button> Fetch latest Gist</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

            );

        }
      });

      var GistBox = React.createClass({

        getInitialState: function() {
            return{
                gists: []
            };
        },
        addGist: function(username) {   
            var url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/gists`;
            console.log("atleast log is working");

            $.get(url, function(result){
                alert("working"); // <-- not working
                console.log("Helloooo");
                var username = result[0].owner.login;
                var url = result[0].html_url;

                var gists = this.state.gists.concat({username , url});

                this.setState({ gists }.bind(this));

            });

        },
        render: function() {
            var newGist = function(gist){
                return (<Gist username={gist.username} url={gist.url} />);

            };

            return(
                <div>
                <h1>GistBox</h1>
                <GistAddForm onAdd={this.addGist} />
                { this.state.gists.map(newGist) }
                </div>
            );
        }
      });

      ReactDOM.render(<GistBox />, document.querySelector('#app'));
      </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: No. in jquery function there is no alert and no console  log is showing. but in other parts its working

Comment: Maybe your url is wrong. What is your console output if you replace `console.log("atleast log is working");` with `console.log(url);`? The `$.get` statement only executes the function if the call is successful.